# Save value from external page into Javascript variable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Let's say I have one page that displays the number "5". The page source code looks like this:

```
5
```

Now, on a different web page, I want to save the contents of this page (5) to a Javascript variable. I'm pretty sure this can be done by using jQuery/AJAX to access the external page, and then grab the contents, but I'm unsure as to how I would write the value into a Javascript variable.

How would you approach this? What code should be used?

Comment: Make a webservice which returns the 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `.get()` function, along with a callback:

```
function get_data(callback) {
    $.get('get.php', function (data) {
        callback(data);
    });
}

function use_data(param) {
    alert(param);
}
```

You can now call the `get_data` function with a callback function. You can do whatever you want to this variable inside that callback, for now, it simply alerts.

```
get_data(use_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `.get()` function

```
var distinctTaxis = 0;
$.get('get.php', {"distinct": "yes"}, function (data) {
    distinctTaxis = data;
});
```

Comment: This isn't working. I am doing this: `var distinctTaxis = 0; $.get('get.php?distinct=yes', function (data) { distinctTaxis = data; }); alert(distinctTaxis);` but the alert still returns 0.

Comment: please see the edited post, you need to pass parameters in the method

Comment: This is an Async function, throwing an alert immediately after isn't going to work. You'll need a callback.

Comment: Alright, thanks for that. By callback, you mean like pressing a button to display the alert?